# Issues with ggplot and the secondary axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot a bar plot and line graph on the same plot with two different y axes. I understand that the secondary y-axis is just visual with ggplot so I am not sure if there is a solution to my issue. I want to see the bar plots more clearly. Currently, you can barely see them even though the secondary y axis is at the appropriate scale (because they are plotting to the primary axis).

This is a subset of my Data. You can see the max value of both my water and clam sample in this data set.

```
date         clam     water
2020-08-26   62.17    3.84
2020-08-31  277.85    1.93
2020-09-08   90.58    4.59
2020-09-22   97.0     0.81
2020-10-12  86.15     0.12
2020-10-20  14.90     0.65
2020-11-09  24.16     0.00
2020-12-10  20.07     0.11
2021-01-05   8.72     0.00
2021-02-10  14.05     0.00
2021-03-30  10.09     0.00
2021-04-22  10.96     0.00
2021-05-18  12.30     0.00
2021-06-01   8.60     0.00
2021-06-16  15.17     0.00
2021-07-07 1045.67    0.28
2021-07-22  61.49     0.41
2021-08-11  25.64     0.00
2021-08-26  15.71     0.16

p <- ggplot(turn, aes(x=date)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = clam, group=1), colour = "black", size = 1) + 
  geom_bar(aes(y=water), stat = "identity", fill="cyan",colour ="#006000")+
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(trans=~./200, name = "water")) + 
  theme_minimal() + 
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=60, hjust=1)) 

p
```

[image: This is a plot of my full data set. You can see that even though water concentrations are 4 they do not appear that way on the secondary y axis]

Comment: A worthwhile read on the topic https://blog.datawrapper.de/dualaxis/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should update ggplot2 because your code doesn't work with the current version.

You need to transform the `water` values if you misuse (in the opinion of the ggplot2 author) secondary axes like this.

```
library(data.table)
turn <- fread("date         clam     water
2020-08-26   62.17    3.84
2020-08-31  277.85    1.93
2020-09-08   90.58    4.59
2020-09-22   97.0     0.81
2020-10-12  86.15     0.12
2020-10-20  14.90     0.65
2020-11-09  24.16     0.00
2020-12-10  20.07     0.11
2021-01-05   8.72     0.00
2021-02-10  14.05     0.00
2021-03-30  10.09     0.00
2021-04-22  10.96     0.00
2021-05-18  12.30     0.00
2021-06-01   8.60     0.00
2021-06-16  15.17     0.00
2021-07-07 1045.67    0.28
2021-07-22  61.49     0.41
2021-08-11  25.64     0.00
2021-08-26  15.71     0.16")

turn[, date := as.Date(date)]

library(ggplot2) #version 3.4.4

#fixed code to work with supplied data
p <- ggplot(turn, aes(x=date)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = clam, group=1), colour = "black", linewidth = 1) + 
  geom_bar(aes(y=water*250), stat = "identity", fill="cyan",colour ="#006000")+
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(trans=~./250, name = "water"),
                     breaks = c(0, 250, 500, 750, 1000, 1250)) + 
  theme_minimal() + theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=60, hjust=1)) 
p
```

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate this - I thought there was a fix. The interpretation about the secondary axis was based on a deep dive of this issue on this site. I was stuck, so thank you for helping.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ggh4x` package to format the secondary axis like

```
library(ggh4x)

df <- read.table(text = "date         clam     water
2020-08-26   62.17    3.84
2020-08-31  277.85    1.93
2020-09-08   90.58    4.59
2020-09-22   97.0     0.81
2020-10-12  86.15     0.12
2020-10-20  14.90     0.65
2020-11-09  24.16     0.00
2020-12-10  20.07     0.11
2021-01-05   8.72     0.00
2021-02-10  14.05     0.00
2021-03-30  10.09     0.00
2021-04-22  10.96     0.00
2021-05-18  12.30     0.00
2021-06-01   8.60     0.00
2021-06-16  15.17     0.00
2021-07-07 1045.67    0.28
2021-07-22  61.49     0.41
2021-08-11  25.64     0.00
2021-08-26  15.71     0.16", header = T)

sec <- help_secondary(df, primary = clam, secondary = water, method = "max")

ggplot(df, aes(x=date)) + 
  geom_col(aes(y=sec$proj(water), fill="water", colour ="#006000"))+
  geom_line(aes(y = clam, group=1, colour = "clam"), size = 1) + 
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec) +
  scale_color_manual(
    values = c(clam = "black", water = "cyan"),
    aesthetics = c("color", "fill")) +
  theme_minimal() + 
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=60, hjust=1))+
  labs(y = "clam", color = NULL, fill = NULL)
```

[image]